# Can't calculate np.cov() correctly

Tags: python, covariance, normal-distribution, probability-density, covariance-matrix

This question might be silly, but i couldn't find an explanation to that.

I am coding the multivariate probability density function from scratch (for study purposes), and one of the things that i need to compute is the covariance matrix of data. I am using the Iris dataset (150 samples, 4 features), and when i code:

```py
cov_matrix = np.cov(X)
print(cov_matrix.shape) // (150,150)
```

I don't understand why it is returning a 150x150 matrix, is this an "element-wise covariance matrix"? Shouldn't it be a 4x4 covariance matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [numpy.cov](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html)'s reference page, there is an argument called `rowvar` which is set to `True` by default. The following paragraph is its explanation:

> If rowvar is True (default), then each row represents a variable, with
> observations in the columns. Otherwise, the relationship is
> transposed: each column represents a variable, while the rows contain
> observations.

So, it assumes the given matrix has observations in the columns. Hence, you either need to input $X^T$ (via `X.T`) or call this function with `rowvar=False`.

Answer (score 2):

By default [Numpy assumes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) that variables are in rows, while observations in columns:

> **rowvar : *bool, optional***
> If rowvar is True (default), then each row represents a variable, with observations in the columns. Otherwise, the relationship is
> transposed: each column represents a variable, while the rows contain
> observations.